# On clickListener on Image in listview

Tags: android, onclicklistener

Am developing a android application which contains listview with imageview and two textviews as in picture attached.So my query here is on click of the image, not on the list item. i should navigate to another activity.My code is as below

[image]

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

String[] animals=new String[]{"Chinkara","Redpanda","Elephant","Squirel","Langur"};

int[] images=new int[]{R.drawable.rsz_rajas_chinkara,R.drawable.rsz_rsz_sikkim_redpanda,R.drawable.rsz_jharkhand_indianelephant,R.drawable.rsz_mh_indiangiantsquirel
        ,R.drawable.rsz_tripura_langur};

String[] country=new String[]{"India","India","India","India","India"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView lst=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    List<HashMap<String,String>> alist=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for(int i=0; i<5;i++)
    {
        HashMap<String,String> hm=new HashMap<String, String>();
        hm.put("txt","Animal :" +animals[i]);
        hm.put("country","Country :" +country[i]);
        hm.put("image", Integer.toString(images[i]));
        alist.add(hm);

    }


    String[] from={"image","txt","country"};

    int[] to={R.id.image,R.id.txt,R.id.country};

    SimpleAdapter adapter=new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), alist, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);
    lst.setAdapter(adapter);

  }
}
```

Comment: you should write code for onclicklistener in adapter...

Comment: Since the question was already answered (n times) just an off-topic: You can use `this` instead of `getBaseContext()` when creating your adapter.

Comment: post your adapter code

Answer (score 1):

try this code in your adapter class getView() method

```
myImageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i=new Intent(context,yourActivity.class);
        startActivity(i); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use custom list adapter & in getView method  setonclicklistener on imageview. refer [cusom list view](http://vaishalibhujbal.com/blogspot/?p=26)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your adapter instead of activity:

```
animalImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //your logic 
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need implement your own adapter and set onclick listeners for the imageview in the  `getView()` Method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to set click action for each item in listview. Implement `onscrolllistener`

```
 lst.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                    int scrollState) {

            }

            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                for (int i = 0; i < lst.getChildCount(); i++) {
                    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) lst
                            .getChildAt(i);
                    // Here "0" is the position of your imageview or
                    // imagebutton
                    ImageView animalImage = (ImageView) layout
                            .getChildAt(0);
                    animalImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // your logic
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
        });
```

**And i suggest use custom adapter**.

But in your case you can do this

Comment: Hi Amsher,what is level1 above here

Comment: Accept the answer which one is helps you. It'll help others.